# Unable to fetch mysql record based on value fetched from a list box in php

Tags: php, mysql, listbox

I have been trying to add a record in mysql through a form. I am able to do so. Once the record has been added, then I fetch all records primary key to populate a list box. at the click event of the list box I want to fetch complete details of the selected record. I have tried through the following code. I am able to add the record and populate the list box, but not fetching the record based on value selected from the list box. Can any body give any suggestions. Thanks in advance. 
My code is as below -

```
<!--
    File Name - insert_and_drop_down_list.php
    This file performs following actions - 
    (1) Insert record into the database table
    (2) Fetch records from the same table, Populate listbox
    (3) At the click event of the listbox, display the data
-->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Insert And Drop Down List</title>
        <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
            function reload(form)
            {
                var e = document.getElementById("lstName");
                var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                //var val=form.lstName.options[form.lstName.options.selectedIndex].value;
                self.location='insert_and_drop_down_list.php?param_name=' + val ;
                //window.alert(val);
                document.write(val);
            }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="insert_and_drop_down_list.php">
            Name : &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txtName"/></br>
            Age : &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txtAge"></br>
            Gender : &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txtGender"/></br>
            Occupation : &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txtOccupation"/><br>
            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Sign Up"/><br/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


<?php
    $name=isset($_REQUEST['txtName'])?$_REQUEST['txtName']:"";
    $age=isset($_REQUEST['txtAge'])?$_REQUEST['txtAge']:"";
    $gender=isset($_REQUEST['txtGender'])?$_REQUEST['txtGender']:"";
    $occupation=isset($_REQUEST['txtOccupation'])?$_REQUEST['txtOccupation']:"";

    $con = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = mysql_select_db("db_insert_and_drop_down_list");

    if(isset ($_REQUEST['btnSubmit']))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_employee(col_name,col_age,col_gender,col_occupation)values('$name','$age','$gender','$occupation')";
        $status=mysql_query($sql);

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY col_name ASC";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql2);





        echo "<select name='lstName' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\">
        <option value=''>Select one</option>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
            echo "<option value='$row[col_name]'>$row[col_name]</option>"."<BR>";
        }
        echo "</select>";

        //echo "<input type='submit' name='btnDisplayRecord' value='Display Record'>";
    }   




    //and strlen($param_name) > 0
    $param_name=isset($_REQUEST['param_name'])?$_REQUEST['param_name']:"";
    echo $param_name;
    if(isset($param_name))
    {
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee WHERE col_name='$param_name'";
        $rs_emp = mysql_query($sql3);

        echo "pppppppppppppppppppppppppp";

        echo "$param_name";

        echo "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn";


        while($row_emp = mysql_fetch_array($rs_emp))
        {
            echo "aaaaaaa";

            echo $row_emp['col_name'];

            //echo "<input type='text' name='txtName' value=".$row_emp['col_emp']."/></br>";
        }
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

and the SQL

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_employee` (
  `col_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `col_age` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `col_gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `col_occupation` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_employee`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_employee` (`col_name`, `col_age`, `col_gender`, `col_occupation`) VALUES
('aa', 11, 'aa', 'aa'),
('aaa', 11, 'aaaaa', 'aaa');
```

Please take a look and give the directions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I don't have to work with this naming structure. `tbl_`,`col_`... It would drive me nuts! Anyway, echo $sql3

Comment: If you are the owner of all this code above, please switch to `PDO` or `MySqli`. New version of PhP, in Appache for example, throw warnings about using deprecated `mysql` methods. If you didn't activated debuging, you could have an error with this.

Comment: I would change `if(isset($param_name))` to  `if(! empty($param_name))` and add an `else` part to easily check which part is processed. But my real approach would be to query for all information directly and hide the details you only want to show on `click`

Answer (score 0):

- It is the current naming convention that is being followed right now > I'm glad I don't have to work with this naming structure. tbl_,col_... It would drive me nuts!
- Since I am working on legacy code, pdo or mysqli is out of question > If you are the owner of all this code above, please switch to PDO or MySqli.
- After going through the code again and again, I have found that original page is not redirecting that is

  self.location='insert_and_drop_down_list.php?param_name=' + val ;

This line fails to redirect to itself and pass the parameter. Since parameter is not passing the whole script fails. I even tried to pass the parameter as below

```
<?php echo Header('Location:insert_and_ddl.php?param_name=' + val)?>
```

But still the page is not redirecting and is not passing the parameter. Any suggestions?